# Releasing class members used in different synchronization contexts

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-management, mutex

I am learning about the singleton design pattern with Chapter 29 of Professional C++, Second Edition<sup>1</sup>.
It illustrates a singleton implementation of a `Logger` class that covers thread-safety requirements:

## Header

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <mutex>
// Definition of a multithread safe singleton logger class
class Logger
{
    public:
        static const std::string kLogLevelDebug;
        static const std::string kLogLevelInfo;
        static const std::string kLogLevelError;
        // Returns a reference to the singleton Logger object
        static Logger& instance();
        // Logs a single message at the given log level
        void log(const std::string& inMessage,
                 const std::string& inLogLevel);
        // Logs a vector of messages at the given log level
        void log(const std::vector<std::string>& inMessages,
                 const std::string& inLogLevel);
    protected:
        // Static variable for the one-and-only instance
        static Logger* pInstance;
        // Constant for the filename
        static const char* const kLogFileName;
        // Data member for the output stream
        std::ofstream mOutputStream;
        // Embedded class to make sure the single Logger
        // instance gets deleted on program shutdown.
        friend class Cleanup;
        class Cleanup
        {
           public:
           ~Cleanup();
        };
        // Logs message. The thread should own a lock on sMutex
        // before calling this function.
        void logHelper(const std::string& inMessage,
                  const std::string& inLogLevel);
    private:
        Logger();
        virtual ~Logger();
        Logger(const Logger&);
        Logger& operator=(const Logger&);
        static std::mutex sMutex;
};
```

## Implementation

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include "Logger.h"
using namespace std;

const string Logger::kLogLevelDebug = "DEBUG";
const string Logger::kLogLevelInfo = "INFO";
const string Logger::kLogLevelError = "ERROR";
const char* const Logger::kLogFileName = "log.out";
Logger* Logger::pInstance = nullptr;
mutex Logger::sMutex;

Logger& Logger::instance()
{
    static Cleanup cleanup;
    lock_guard<mutex> guard(sMutex);
    if (pInstance == nullptr)
        pInstance = new Logger();
    return *pInstance;
}
Logger::Cleanup::~Cleanup()
{
    lock_guard<mutex> guard(Logger::sMutex);
    delete Logger::pInstance;
    Logger::pInstance = nullptr;
}
Logger::~Logger()
{
    mOutputStream.close();
}
Logger::Logger()
{
    mOutputStream.open(kLogFileName, ios_base::app);
    if (!mOutputStream.good()) {
        throw runtime_error("Unable to initialize the Logger!");
    }
}
void Logger::log(const string& inMessage, const string& inLogLevel)
{
    lock_guard<mutex> guard(sMutex);
    logHelper(inMessage, inLogLevel);
}
void Logger::log(const vector<string>& inMessages, const string& inLogLevel)
{
    lock_guard<mutex> guard(sMutex);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < inMessages.size(); i++) {
        logHelper(inMessages[i], inLogLevel);
    }
}
void Logger::logHelper(const std::string& inMessage,
    const std::string& inLogLevel)
{
    mOutputStream << inLogLevel << ": " << inMessage << endl;
}
```

It goes on to explain why the friend class `Cleanup` is introduced:

> The `Cleanup` class is there to make sure the single `Logger` instance
>   gets deleted properly on program shutdown. This is necessary because
>   this implementation is dynamically allocating the `Logger` instance by
>   using the new operator in a block of code protected with a mutex. A
>   static instance of the `Cleanup` class will be created the first time
>   the instance() method is called. When the program terminates, the C++
>   runtime will destroy this static `Cleanup` instance, which will trigger
>   the deletion of the `Logger` object and a call to the `Logger` destructor
>   to close the file.

I find it very confusing that it states "*This is necessary because...*", as if there were no other alternative.

My questions:

1) Is it really necessary? Wouldn't it be enough to just have all the handling in the destructor?, like:

```
Logger::~Logger()
{
    {
        lock_guard<mutex> guard(Logger::sMutex);
        delete Logger::pInstance;
        Logger::pInstance = nullptr;
    }
    mOutputStream.close();
}
```

2) If the answer to 1) is "yes, it is indeed necessary!", I would like to know why.

<sup>1</sup>Professional C++, Second Edition by Marc Gregoire , Nicholas A. Solter , Scott J. Kleper Publisher: Wrox Published: October 2011

Comment: What would trigger `Logger`'s destructor?

Comment: Always free what you allocate, or you would have a resource leak. Remember that not all operating-systems does this for you.

Comment: BTW, use Meyers' Singleton and you won't need this (instance is not a pointer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is needed in this case.  Since the book used `new` and handed out a pointer there is no object that will go out of scope that will cause the destructor to fire.  The only way to do so is to call `delete` somewhere on that pointer.  Instead of requiring you to do that the `Cleanup` class was created to do that.

All of this though can be avoided if you use a Meyers Singleton.  That uses a static variable of the singleton type and returns a pointer/reference to that.  That will automatically be destroyed at the end of the program unlike the book version.  A Meyers Singleton looks like:

```
class Singleton {
public:
    static Singleton* Instance() { static Singleton s; return &s; }
    Singleton(const Singleton&) = delete;
    void operator=(const Singleton&) = delete;
private:
    Singleton() = default;
};
```

Comment: You answer leaves me wondering if the referred book is any good. I mean, I learned a lot from comparing its proposed variant of singleton against the Meyer's alternative, but when in need for a quick reference of design patterns, is there a book that documents implementations in their most accepted form?

Comment: @levelont Not sure but [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) is a great place to start your search